# How do I get the right regex in the url conf for this string?

Tags: python, regex, url, youtube-api

The current regex is:

```
url(r'^partner/(?P<author>[-\w]+)/(?P<video>\w+)/(?P<title>\w+)/$', 'video_player'),
```

I've been trying for while now and can't get it to work where title (last argument) will accept the below 2 sample strings:

- Zombie Apocalypse!: The (100+) Life-Saving Skills You Need from the
  "Expert" or so they say?
- http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/k8J-72MmTGg/related?v=2

Any advice?

## edit

Here is some text that isn't working when I pass it as a parameter for title:
The National Baseball Hall of Fame shows off 6 pieces of Yankees postseason memorabilia: a watch from the 1923 World Series; Babe Ruth's bat from the 1926 World Series; Yogi Berra's glove from Don Larsen's perfect game in 1956; the last out ball in the 1962 World Series; Derek Jeter's jersey from the 1996 World Series; Mariano Rivera's hat from the 2000 Subway Series.

http://www.buzzfeed.com/sports

Comment: Could you provide more code or explain more what you are trying to do with the XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\w+` Is a regular expression that will match only alphanumeric characters, and the underscore.
I will try to show a strict solution to the examples you give and a more general that might be the one that also works for you.

Since you like to match other characters, which are not included in the `w` group, you should make a custom group, adding the special characters you need.
To form a group, you write it between brackets [].
To add characters to the group just write them one after another, except the `-` since it can define a range, you have to put it in front.
For the first example, you need to match characters like the parenthesis and plus sign, that are special for regex, so have to be escaped.
For + -> use +
For ( -> use (
So the regex for the first example would start looking like this:
`[\w\(\)\+]+`
For a cheatsheet on regex, you can look at: [Cheat sheet](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html) or [downloadable](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/)
After adding the - sign at the beginning to avoid ranges, and the other escaped and non-escaped characters. A group that would match both strings would look like:

`[-\w\/\?:=\.\s!\(\)"\+]+`

Since this is complicated and you seem to want to get almost anything as a title I recommend the special group `.` since it includes any character, except newline.

The regexp will look very simply:
`.+`

Comment: I tried passing the text that I included in the edit above, and it doesn't seem to match.  Any advice?

Comment: Hi sharataka, apologies for the late reply. Does the text include newline characters?

Answer (score 0):

```
url(r'^partner/(?P<author>[-\w]+)/(?P<video>\w+)/(?P<title>.*)/$', 'video_player'),
```

Should get you there. Just caputure everything after the video match until the final /